# Redirect after login React js

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out how to solve this.
I have a login page, after the login you should be redirect to your profile page.
I got this error:
No routes matched location "/Profile/Profile"

my files structure looks like this:

- Components (folder)
- - Login (folder)
- - - Login.jsx
- - Profile (folder)
- - - Profile.jsx

Login.jsx

```
const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // User login info
    const database = [{
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
    }
    ];

    // Error messages
    const errors = {
        uname: "invalid username",
        pass: "invalid password"
    };


    const handlesubmit=(event)=>{

        // Prevent page reload
        event.preventDefault();
        var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];

        // Find user login info
        const userData = database.find((user) => user.username === uname.value);

        // Compare user info
        if (userData) {
            if (userData.password !== pass.value) {
              // Invalid password
              setErrorMessages({ name: "pass", message: errors.pass });
            } else {
              setIsSubmitted(true);
              navigate("../Profile/Profile");
            }
          } else {
            // Username not found
            setErrorMessages({ name: "uname", message: errors.uname });
        }

    };
```

Comment: How exactly are you defining your routes using React Router?

Comment: do you mean: 
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

?

Comment: @adcoding he is asking about how you defined your routes for your pages (maybe in your App.js). Something like so:
<Route path="/Profile">
      <Profile />
</Route>

Comment: oh yes:
```
<Router>
<div className='menu-header'>
<Link to='/Login'>Login</Link>
<Link to='/Register'>Register</Link>
</div>
<Routes>
<Route path="/Login" caseSensitive={false} element={<Login />} />
<Route path="/Register" caseSensitive={false} element={<Register />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>```